# Recursive os.scandir() for copying/moving files preserving subdirectories

Tags: python, recursion, file-system

This is modified from the general recursive solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54544211/42346 to, more specifically, copy/move files with a given extension from one directory to another whilst preserving subdirectories.

I'm reluctant to use `.rename()` for this purpose as it seems slightly less intuitive than copying or moving.

Any other ideas you have about how to clean this up are greatly appreciated.

```
import os, shutil
from pathlib import Path

def recur(path,destination,file_ext,is_subdir=False):
    if not is_subdir:
        os.chdir(path)
    for entry in os.scandir(path): 
        if os.path.splitext(entry.name)[-1].lower() == file_ext:
            subdir_path = entry.path.replace(os.getcwd() + os.sep,'')
            new_path = Path(destination) / subdir_path 
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(new_path), exist_ok=True) 
            shutil.copy(entry.path,new_path)
        if entry.is_dir():
            recur(Path(path).joinpath(entry.name),destination,file_ext,is_subdir=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `pathlib.Path`, which is great, but it can do a lot more:

- Operations like `os.path.splitext` should be modernized using the `suffix` attribute of `Path` objects; for a full list of those designated replacements, see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module).
- `os.scandir` can in this case be replaced by `Path.rglob`. This is where the recursion you mentioned comes into play. But that's it: Recursive globbing is an irrelevant implementation detail here. The point is that we do not have to do it "manually". `rglob` takes a pattern as its string argument, which can be the suffix you mentioned.
- Further, `os.makedirs` can be `Path.mkdir` with `parents=True` for the latter. This is not as big a win as the others, but nice.

Eventually, it turns out the `os` import can be done without altogether, and recursion is neatly tucked away:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy2  # "identical to copy() but attempts to preserve to file metadata"

COPY_FROM = Path("source")
COPY_TO = Path("dest")

SUFFIX = "*.py"

for source in COPY_FROM.rglob(SUFFIX):
    subpath = source.relative_to(COPY_FROM)
    destination = COPY_TO.joinpath(subpath)
    destination.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    copy2(source, destination)
```

Note the use of `copy2`, which is [identical to `copy` but attempts to preserve metadata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2).
This can be convenient for e.g. music files.

The `parent` attribute is the logical parent path to the found file, so essentially all path elements except for the found file itself.
Like in your solution, those path elements (directories) have to be created first.
In `mkdir`, `exist_ok=False` is the default and would prohibit us from most desired operations, like copying files in subdirectories.

The above gives the following result, which is hopefully what you are aiming for:

```
~$ tree
.
├── dest
│   ├── file1.py
│   ├── test1
│   │   ├── file2.py
│   │   └── file3.py
│   └── test2
│       ├── file4.py
│       └── test3
│           └── file5.py
└── source
    ├── file1.py
    ├── test1
    │   ├── file2.py
    │   └── file3.py
    └── test2
        ├── file4.py
        └── test3
            └── file5.py
```